# How to instantiate object class that contains GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, particles, gameobject

I am attempting to instantiate a large number of "particles" using a C# script in Unity. I have created a particle class that contains the creation of a corresponding GameObject. The GameObject within each particle instance is a sphere. When attempting to instantiate a new particle (Particle p = new Particle(...)) I get a Unity warning that the 'new' keyword should not be used.

*"You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()"*

What is the proper way to instantiate a number of instances of my particle class (each containing a singular sphere GameObject)?

**Particle Class:**

```
public class Particle : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
    Vector3 force = new Vector3();
    Vector3 gravity = new Vector3(0,-9.81f,0);
    int age;
    int maxAge;
    int mass;
    GameObject gameObj = new GameObject();

    public Particle(Vector3 position, Vector3 velocity)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.force = Vector3.zero;
        age = 0;
        maxAge = 250;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);

        //gameObj.transform.localScale (1, 1, 1);
        gameObj.transform.position = position;
    }

    // FixedUopdate is called at a fixed rate - 50fps
    void FixedUpdate () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
        velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        //transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        gameObj.transform.position = velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        Debug.Log ("Velocity: " + velocity);
        //this.position = this.position + (this.velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        //gameObj.transform.position
    }
}
```

**CustomParticleSystem Class:**

```
public class CustomParticleSystem : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 initPos = new Vector3(0, 15, 0);
    Vector3 initVel = Vector3.zero;
    private Particle p;
    ArrayList Particles = new ArrayList();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Particle p = new Particle (initPos, initVel);
        Particles.Add (p);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine other than you may have accidentally typed the declaration wrong for `gameObj`

Change `GameObject gameObj = new GameObject();` to just `GameObject gameObj = null;` in your `Particle` class.

The error specifically mentions that you cannot do what you did and in your `Start()` you are setting it like it mentioned.

EDIT: Looking at `Particle`, it inherits `MonoBehaviour`. You need to have `gameObject` create the instance for you using `gameObject.AddComponent<Particle>();`

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

`gameObject` is defined on `MonoBehaviour` so you should have access to it already.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the only change that should be made is the initialization of the GameObject to null within the Particle class. However, I am still receiving the warning regarding not using the 'new' keyword within CustomParticleSystem's Start method. The code runs, but no particle is visible at the hardcoded initial position in the scene.

Comment: @MattKoczwara Ah. I see. Your `Particle` is a `MonoBehaviour`. You need to get an instance of `GameObject` and then set your particles to `gameObject.AddComponent<Particle>()` in `CustomParticleSystem `

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Would you happen to know how to then access the properties/methods for each particle/gameObject?

Comment: @MattKoczwara Not sure exactly what you are referring to. If you do `Particle p = gameObject.AddComponent<Particle>();` you should be able to have full access to all properties on `p`.

Comment: I see that the properties are available once a particle is set to the gameObject. Thanks again.